# How to write comments within .conkyrc config file?

Tags: conky

How to write comments within a `.conkyrc` config file?

Comment: And that is programming *how*?

Comment: Because with conky you can program a range of monitoring tools. No need to explain in much further. People who use it would understand.

Comment: I do understand conky, and I don't find it software development at all, it's a system monitoring tool. Please use [su] or [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Comment: The way I see it, as far you can write comments and instructions it's 100% software development. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below some quick examples:

```
-- Comment one
    -- Comment two
--     Comment three
--Comment four
```

You need to use "--" on each line you would like to place a comment on

Comment: Not working for me on raspbian Buster while commenting out things I don't want conky to process